why pyinstaller failed to find files for numpy dependency?
I am still struggling with cython and pyinstaller to package a python script, say appX.py with a folder containing a pyd file.
I modified appX.spec to include options for hidden imports, which includes numpy used in the pyd file.
But when pyInstaller runs, it gives the following error message:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\prgm\\appX\\dist\\appX\\_internal\\numpy.libs\\libopenblas64__v0.3.23-293-gc2f4bdbb-gcc_10_3_0-2bde3a66a51006b2b53eb373ff767a3f.dll'

Since the bottom folder name is numpy.libs, I would guess this means pyinstaller failed to packaging the dependency for numpy.  Then I googled and downloaded
libopenblas64__v0.3.23-293-gc2f4bdbb-gcc_10_3_0-2bde3a66a51006b2b53eb373ff767a3f.dll

from the following page:
https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/libopenblas64_v0_3_23-293-gc2f4bdbb-gcc_10_3_0-2bde3a66a51006b2b53eb373ff767a3f/5e46c3d334c90c3029eb6ae2a3fe58f2/download

But somehow Windows refused to move or copy the file from my download folder to the numpy.libs folder in the package.
Basically, I am now lost in this packaging procedure.
I would appreciate if anyone can shed lights on the following questions.

What is the progress status of pyinstaller in this packaing?
Has pyinstaller finished every packaging steps but this numpy dll file downloading?  If that is true, does it mean I can find some way to move the dll to numpy.libs and distribute the dist folder to my clients?
If that is false, then does that mean I need to rerun the pyinstaller from the beginning?  But then how should I get over with the missing dll problem?  　If I manually move the dll file to numpy.libs, will the problem be solved or will it be removed by pyinstaller?
Finally, how should I move this dll file to folder numpy.libs without triggering the long file path problem?

Thanks!  Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.
